# Variable to which Linq Query assigned has never the value of NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
var query = from k in entity.Candidates where k.CandidateId == candidateid select k;

if(query==null)
{
    return false;
}
```

I have been checking if the variable `query` has the value of null. But realized, even if the result set returns nothing query is not equal to null. Never goes into the if block.
How can I simply check if the result set has nothing?

Comment: You have generated a query - you have not executed it yet. This is a common mistake for developers new to LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behavior: the query object is not the same thing as the item returned from the `IQueryable` object encapsulates. Since you did not run that query, the check

```
if (query==null)
```

verifies that the `IQueryable` object has been created successfully.

To check the results of the query you need to attempt running it, or to call an aggregating method on it:

- You could run `ToList()` and check the `Count` of the result, or
- Call a `Any()` on the query to see if there are any results, or
- Call `FirstOrDefault()`, and compare its result to `null`.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong; the value of `query` will be an empty `IEnumerable` when there is no matching record in the database. There is no object that represents the definition of the query; it's just the OP's variable naming.

Comment: @DanPuzey I think OP's using `IQueryable`, not `IEnumerable`. I made corrections to the answer to avoid ambiguities present in the original answer. Thanks!

Comment: Huh, I never considered that a call to set up a query might return null. Pretty paranoid :D